# Read partially unordered data into columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamic-data, data-extraction

Taking part in [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com) I'm currently trying to figure out a solution for puzzle 2 of day 4. As I usually only work in Java but recently need to work in Python at work I thought it would be a good idea to do this in Python as an exercise - hence my knowledge of the language is quite low.

However, the problem is the following: I'm given an input file which contains data for passports. Each passport is separated by "\n\n", so there is one empty line between the data of two passports. However, a passport should contain 8 key-value pairs that can be separated either by a space character or by "\n" and there is no specific order to any of these fields - also it may occur that a passport doesn't contain certain fields.

For better understanding I'll give you an example how two passports may look like:

```
hgt:183cm
pid:368895060
ecl:oth eyr:2020
iyr:2013
byr:1966

ecl:lzr cid:279 pid:192cm
hcl:1f7352 iyr:2014 hgt:70cm eyr:1983
byr:2004
```

I thought it might be a good idea to bring that data into a table representation using pandas' data frame, however I'm not really sure how to accomplish this. My first attempt was this but it throws a ton of errors at me when executing (and I also get that it wouldn't work like this anyways):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('puzzle_inputs/puzzle_input_4.txt', sep="\s+", header = 0, names=["byr", "iyr", "eyr", "hgt", "hcl", "ecl", "pid", "cid"])
data
```

Obviously I would need to get rid of the field identifiers like "byr:" but I also need them to insert the data into the right columns as for example the second pid in the example data above contains a value that could very well also be a value for height. I'm entirely confused how one would do this as I'm not used to work with data extraction in this way since I usually only build UI applications that utilize a structure database and not data files that need to be accessed dynamically.

Any help is really much appreciated as I'm quite lost here.

Comment: kinda easier if you don't use pandas. 1. read the file. 2. Split at '\n\n' to get list of passports. 3.for each passport replace "\n"  and split by space 4. for each value split by ":" and get key,values. 5.use whatever condition mentioned to verify if valid or not

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do that. It was actually my first approach to this task but I didn't split the key value pairs like you mentioned. Perhaps this would have been a better idea.